# What does [ N ... M ] mean in C aggregate initializers?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

From [sys.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.1/arch/unicore32/kernel/sys.c#L123) line 123:

```
void *sys_call_table[__NR_syscalls] = 
{
    [0 ... __NR_syscalls-1] = sys_ni_syscall,
#include <asm/unistd.h>
};
```

`sys_call_table` is a generic pointer to arrays, I can see that. However what is the notation:

```
[0 ... __NR_syscalls-1]
```

What is the `...`?

---

**EDIT:**
I learned another C trick here: `#include <asm/unistd.h>` will be *preprocessed* and replaced with its content and assigned to `[0 ... _NR_syscalls-1]`.

Comment: No, it's not a pointer to an array, it's an array of pointers. A pointer to an array would be declared `void (*sys_call_table)[__NR_syscalls]`

Comment: @tristopia you're right. What I meant was pointer to arrays, similar to `char *argv[]`. Fixed.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It is initialization using **[Designated Initializers](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html)**.

The range based initialization is a gnu gcc extension.

> To initialize a range of elements to the same value, write `[first ... last] = value`. This is a GNU extension. For example,
>
> ```
>  int widths[] = { [0 ... 9] = 1, [10 ... 99] = 2, [100] = 3 };
> ```

It is not portable. Compiling with `-pedantic` with tell you so.

**How does it work here?**
The preprocessor replaces `#include <asm/unistd.h>` with its actual contents(*it defines miscellaneous symbolic constants and types, and declares miscellaneous functions*) in the range based construct, which are then further used for initializing the array of pointers.

Comment: It seems this is not portable. Is is?

Comment: @Mehrdad does microsoft c compiler complies to c99 standard? I rest my case here...[c99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Actually, only the range based construct of Designated Initializers is an gcc extension.Designated Initializers themselves are allowed by the C standard.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Sorry, I do not wish to be part of any flame baits,my intention was only to clarify a subtle detail which I thought you misunderstood.

Comment: @Mehrdad: To be clear, the range construct portable only to gcc (and compilers that implements its extensions), and designated initializers in general are portable only to compilers that support C99 (or at least that particular feature).

Comment: @aftnix Which Microsoft C Compiler? They only have a C++ compiler with support for some of the C functionality.

Comment: @RedX so msft does not want their visual studio tools users to develop stuffs in c? but what about this ? [c++ in kernel mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487420.aspx)

Comment: @aftnix I don't really understand your argument... They do want suff developed in C, that's why they extended their C++ compiler with <b>some</b> C functions. I just don't like it when people complain that a <b>clearly</b> labeled C++ compiler does not conform to C89,C99 standards.

Comment: @RedX i get your argument, but its still not a modern 'c' compiler. I just hate to initialize structures using {foo,bar,"eat flaming death",....} style :). i lose track of the fields. Its ok that msft endorses c++. they have every right to do that. but still its not a good platform to develop c stuffs. guys developing c stuffs in visual c++ are missing out all the good stuffs in latest standards.

Comment: are there  equivalent for none-GNU compiler??