# How to repair : struct _reent r = {0, (FILE *) 0 }? Is struct _reent a part of any toolchain?

Tags: c, cross-compiling, atmel

When compiling Atmel example with arm cross-compiler getting :

**../at91lib/utility/stdio.c:64:8: error: variable 'r' has initializer but incomplete type**

the code is :

```
struct _reent r = {0, (FILE *) 0, (FILE *) 1, (FILE *) 0};
```

I don't know what can I do here since first I need here is to understand what this code must mean?

And then can I re code it for my compiler? Or must I downgrade compiler to some other version?

My version :
arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi-gcc (Buildroot 2012.05-git-00423-g4205dbd) 4.5.3

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this style of syntax in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071304/what-is-this-style-of-syntax-in-c)

Comment: I would guess that `struct _reent` hasn't been defined anywhere, and that's what the compiler's complainging about.

Comment: @Als that's a related but distinct question. That question asks about the initializer. This one asks about the error message.

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://www.at91.com/forum/viewtopic.php/f,8/t,5352/

Comment: "had to use Sourcery G++ Lite 2008q3-39 for ARM EABI from ... release567 Anything newer or older gave (different) errors." weird weird weird very weird!

Comment: @Binyamin Sharet I'm not sure what is better put your comment on answer or just remove this question?

Comment: @Alessa - I posted it as answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AT91SAM community](http://www.at91.com/forum/viewtopic.php/f,8/t,5352/):

> It looks like you have to use exactly the right version of compiler:
>   To get sam-ba applets to compile under linux you have to use Sourcery
>   G++ Lite 2008q3-39 for ARM EABI from
>   http://www.codesourcery.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release567 Anything
>   newer or older gives (different) errors.